# ArcGIS Enterprise SSL error when loading hosted feature service

Tags: arcgis-web-adaptor, arcgis-enterprise, ssl

**Long story short: An item from our portal server is skipping around the portal URL, and loading as its own resource. This is causing a problem because the server does not have its own certificate. It should be bundled up with the portal resources.**

*Note: https://internal.gis.bisnet.com is on https://server01.ina.bisnet.com*

We have ArcGIS Enterprise deployed. Everything is secure, however when a hosted feature service is loaded in a new web map, the site is flagged as insecure.

In Google Chrome Developer tools, I loaded the site to understand what insecure resource was being loaded.

- It notes that my portal site (https://internal.gis.bisnet.com --example) IS secure.
- However, it is also showing the name of the server that portal is on (https://server01.ina.bisnet.com) as an INSECURE resource. This is interesting, because everything should be coming through the portal URL (internal.gis.bisnet.com).

[image: Google Chrome security]

I took a look at the Google Chrome *sources* list, to determine what resource was loading from server01 (skipping around portal).

- It is an item from our Webadaptor (called team)
- It appears to be something under the "self" properties

[image: sources]

How do I modify my settings so this resource travels through portal, and does not appear as its own resource?

Comment: So your GIS Server is still using a self signed cert?  I assume this is not unique to just one hosted feature service from your hosting server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out the problem. It was a misconfigured web adaptor. When going to PortalAdmin --> System | Web Adaptors |  , the URL was set to the machine name rather than the FQDN.

We just added "/edit" to the end of the page URL, taking you to a place where you can edit that URL parameter. Then we changed URL to the FQDN. Problem solved.

We found the answer on page 324 of "Mastering ArcGIS Enterprise Administration" by @chad-cooper